# How to remove animation for this jQuery modal plugin?

Tags: jquery

How can I remove the animation from this jQuery modal window? You can see the example of the plugin here:

[link text](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/#animationCallbacks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you should delete this:

```
.animate({ // Set the width
  width: settings.width+'px',
  marginLeft: (settings.marginLeft)+'px',
  opacity: 0.5
}, {duration: 350})
.animate({ // Set the height
  height: settings.height+'px',
  marginTop: (settings.marginTop)+'px',
  opacity: 1
}, {complete: callback, duration: 350});
```